# Undefined symbol: cblas_dtrsm

Tags: python, neural-network, dlib

I wrote a python code that thanks to the use of a cnn offered by dlib is able to process photos and recognize faces in these.
My code runs remotely on another computer in which I use a specially configured virtual environment.
The problem is that when I run the code I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "cnn_face_show.py", line 2, in <module>
    import hashlib, os, sys, cv2, PIL, dlib, subprocess, glob
ImportError: /usr/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/dlib.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so: undefined symbol: cblas_dtrsm
```

I've pretty much installed all the packages I need,
how can I do?

Comment: The `cblas` library is probably missing or not properly linked. What system are you running on?

Comment: CentOS Linux release 7.6.1810 (Core), I recently reinstalled BLAS library, maybe I was wrong, how can I install it?

Comment: I think `yum install` should work. Try installing `cblas`, `lapack` and `atlas` If yum doesn't do it, you have to do it manually. http://www.ifp.illinois.edu/grouper/clapack.html